# Index a list in Python with number if list index not outside of range

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, list-comprehension

I'm building a parser in Python and in one step of the parser it needs to look at the next few lines to determine if a value is there. To do this, I'm doing the following:

```
if "Account Summary" in line:
    end_bal_regex = r"Ending balance on (.*?)\s+(-?\$[\d,]+\.\d\d)"
    end_date, end_bal = [re.search(end_bal_regex, text[i+j], re.IGNORECASE).groups() for j in range(1,16) if re.search(r"Ending balance", text[i+j], re.IGNORECASE)][0]
```

This works fine 99% of the time, but sometimes there are not 15 lines of text after the line that has "Account Summary". Is there a way, in list comprehension to say something like `text[i+j] or text[i:]` (obviously pseudo code)? My assumption is that I'll have to convert this to a normal `for` loop and do something like this:

```
if "Account Summary" in line:
    end_date, end_bal = None, None
    for j in range(1,16):
      if j > len(text[i:]):
          break
      if re.search(r"Ending balance", text[i+j], re.IGNORECASE):
          end_date, end_bal = re.search(end_bal_regex, text[i+j], re.IGNORECASE).groups()
```

I'd really like to not have to rewrite all of my various lines of code (there are multiple just like this one) to this format, but I'm not aware of anything that achieves what I need. Any insight or advice is appreciated.

For a reproducible example, you can use the following:

```
lines = ["Account Summary", "Beginning Balance", "Random Text 1", "Random Text 2", "Random Text 3", "Random Text 4", "Ending Balance"]
```

Comment: I don't quite understand fully what you're doing, but I'd guess use `line[line.index("Account Summary"):]` to return all the values after `"Account Summary"`, no matter how many/little there are (or at least use that to get how many values there are), instead of using 16.

Comment: @Peter I think your first suggestion could work quite nicely if there is not a "built in" approach to this problem. Although, one could easily argue that `try/except` IS a built in approach to this problem. The second approach would be too much since there can be upwards of 500 to 1,000 lines of text and I don't want to check all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the limit 16 to `min(16, len(text[i:]))`

```
... for j in range(1, min(16, len(text[i:]))) re.search(r"Ending balance", text[i+j], re.IGNORECASE)][0]
```

Comment: Sigh... it's always the easiest solution that I never realize.